# How to turn off display of div

Tags: javascript, css, algolia

I am trying to delete the empty gray bracket in the picture.
I have tried `tag:empty` and `display: none` but it is not working for me.

[image: preview]

```css
.tag:empty {
   display: none;
}

.tag {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-bottom-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    color: #666;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 3px 12px;
}
```

```html
templates: {
    empty: '<div id="empty">No startup companies have been found for {{ query }}.</div><br>',
    item: `
        <a href="{{linkUrl}}">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="item1">
                <img src="{{logoUrl}}" alt="{{hits-image}}" id="hits-image">
            </div>
            <div class="item2" id="title">
                {{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "title" }{{/helpers.highlight}}
            </div>
            <div class="item3">
                <div id="location">
                    {{#_isLocation}}{{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "location" }{{/helpers.highlight}}{{/_isLocation}}
                </div>
                <div class="tag">
                    {{tagList}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></a>
      `,
    },
}),
```

Please advise, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The `div` element with class `tag` is not empty: in the pictured code it contains a space, and in the template code it contains white space around the Mustache (?) replacement brackets. Per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty),

> The :empty CSS pseudo-class represents any element that has no children. Children can be either element nodes or text (including whitespace).

A quick console log confirms the presence of child nodes:

```js
console.log(mt.firstChild.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
```

```html
<div class="tag" id="mt"> </div>
```

You should be able to use the `:empty` pseudo class by  ensuring there is no white space within `tag` class elements, either by moving start and end tags together, using HTML comments around any white space in source (line feeds etc.), or setting elements' content to the empty string:

```css
.tag {
   width: 50px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: cyan;
}
.tag:empty {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
Empty <code>div.tag</code> (no child nodes)
➡️<div class="tag"></div>⬅️
<p></p>

Non empty <code>div.tag</code> (contains white space)
   ➡️<div class="tag"> 

   </div>⬅️
```

As already answered, including a period before `tag` in the CSS rule for `.tag:empty` is also required for syntax purposes.